# Do a correct union on two List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, .net, list, union, selectlistitem

```
retval.AddRange(oldList.Union(newList));
```

Both the `oldList` and `newList` are declared here

```
List<SelectListItem> oldList = new List<SelectListItem>();
List<SelectListItem> newList = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

I want to union these two lists, removing duplicate items that have the same "text" property. If there is a dupe between newList and oldList on the text property, it should keep the text/value pair of the newList.

The above union doesn't seem to be doing anything besides concat'ing the lists almost, don't know why.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to union these two lists, removing duplicate items that have the same "text" property.

The `Union` method will not handle this requirement.  You could do this via:

```
retVal.AddRange(newList); // Since you want to keep all newList items, do this first

// Add in all oldList items where there isn't a match in new list
retVal.AddRange(oldList.Where(i => !newList.Any(n => i.Text == n.Text)));
```

Comment: @Reed: `newList.Union(oldList)` will do it.  See my response.

Comment: @Jim: Only if the equality comparers handle this the way the OP expected.  However, given his statement, the comparer is not doing the comparison the OP wants... (it's probably checking Text and Value, not just Text for equality).

Comment: This query has abysmal performance. The correct way is to build a HashSet or use a GroupJoin.

Comment: @usr: Again, HashSet and GroupJoin would perform better, but would require a different equality operation in order to function properly.

Comment: You would build the hashset on newList.Select(x => x.Text); then no custom comparer is required. The group join does not need it either.

Comment: @usr: Yes - the hash set *could* speed it up, if the collections are large, at the cost of extra memory usage.  If the collections are small, it will likely cause it to perform more slowly.  Right now, it's O(N^2) as written, though - so if the collections are large, it will perform slowly.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) it appears that `A.Union(B)` in effect just adds to `A` those items from `B` that aren't already in `A`.  That is:

> When the object returned by this
>   method is enumerated, Union enumerates
>   first and second in that order and
>   yields each element that has not
>   already been yielded.

A quick test bears that out.  So `oldList.Union(newList)` will keep the old values whereas `newList.Union(oldList)` will give you the new values.

Here's my test code:

```
    class MyThing
    {
        public string Text { get; private set; }
        public int Version { get; private set; }

        public MyThing(string t, int v)
        {
            Text = t;
            Version = v;
        }

        public override int  GetHashCode()
        {
             return Text.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            MyThing other = obj as MyThing;
            if (other == null)
                return false;
            return this.Text.Equals(other.Text);
        }
    }

    static List<MyThing> oldList = new List<MyThing>()
    {
        new MyThing("Foo", 0),
        new MyThing("Bar", 0),
        new MyThing("Fooby", 0),
    };

    static List<MyThing> newList = new List<MyThing>()
    {
        new MyThing("Barby", 1),
        new MyThing("Bar", 1)
    };

    static void DoIt()
    {
        var unionOldNew = oldList.Union(newList);
        Console.WriteLine("oldList.Union(newList)");
        foreach (var t in unionOldNew)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", t.Text, t.Version);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        var unionNewOld = newList.Union(oldList);
        Console.WriteLine("newList.Union(oldList)");
        foreach (var t in unionNewOld)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", t.Text, t.Version);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This only works if the Equals comparison in the type is setup properly.  This is obviously not the case in the OP's class, as he explicitly mentioned that Union was doing a Concat (which means it's not just limited to his Text property)